# How do I print the value of a setting in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Say I have the following setting in my vscode `settings.json` file,

```
"java.home": "${workspaceRoot}/java/jdk64/",
```

I want to see the resolved value of `java.home` in the console or equivalent. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

[MS recommends](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_how-can-i-know-a-variables-actual-value) to use a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) for this. To get the resolved value of a [configuration variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_configuration-variables), you can create a task like the following:

```json
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "echo ${config:java.home}"
    }
```

Running the task will show the resolved value:

[image: running echo task]

Comment: this will echo `${workspaceRoot}/java/jdk64/`, not very helpful because we already know this from the GUI or `settings.json` file

Comment: @rioV8 I added a screenshot to show that it will print the resolved value; not just copy the value from `settings.json`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will get a better answer but you can print any variable values by setting up a task:

```
 {
  "label": "echo",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "echo",
  "args": ["${workspaceRoot}"]
},
```

and run that task.  So you could substitute

```
  "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/java/jdk64/"]
```