# How to show settings value in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, config

For simple setting key value like  editor.tabSize, I already know we can print it through this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57778850/3426137

But for complex nested object type, for example

```
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "xaver.clang-format"
    }
```

Tried the `${config:[cpp]}` and `${config:'[cpp]'}` but obviously that does not work.

Comment: what is the use case of knowing the setting has changed for `cpp`

Comment: @rioV8 I have some private settings not applied, this [cpp] setting is just an example, so I want to print those setting values to further debug what happened.